# Separate input and print threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was just wandering how to print text while waiting for the users input. Like for example if we were in a chat app, we have an `input()` so that the user could send messages and `print()` when receiving messages. It needs to be simultaneous. I tried to use threads but it always stops at a thread.

Example:

```
def receive(client):
    threadName = client.getThreadName()
    while not client.isStopThread():
        time.sleep(1)
        print('test')
        while (client.isThereMessage()):
            print('[' + threadName + ']: ' + client.getMessage())
```

and for the main program

```
client.startThread(thread.uid)
receiveThread = Thread(target = receive(client))
receiveThread.deamon = True
receiveThread.start()

while True:
    toSendMessage = input('[' + client.fetchThreadInfo(client.uid)[client.uid].name + ']: ')
    client.sendMessage(toSendMessage, thread_id=thread.uid, thread_type=thread.type)
```

Comment: it keeps printing 'test' but there is no '[xx]: ' in there and i can't write some input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `Thread` class constructor incorrectly. The signature is:

```
threading.Thread(target=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

The `target` is the function *object* itself, i.e., `receive`, not `receive(client)`. You're now *calling* the `receive` function with `client` as the input, and then passing the *return value* of that function (which appears to be `None`) as the `target` keyword-argument to the `Thread` constructor. If the `receive` function loops indefinitely, then the code will definitely stall in the `Thread` constructor.

You should instead call the `Thread` constructor like so:

```
receiveThread = Thread(target=receive, args=(client,))
```

Also, in general, you don't need threading to both print something and wait for input. You can instead do what is called *synchronous I/O multiplexing*, which means performing I/O on multiple objects at the same time, but from a single thread. The idea is to wait for notification from the OS when one or more objects are available for either writing or reading (or both). Look at the `select` or `selectors` modules for more information.

Here is a simple example. It just waits for up to one second for input from the user. If input is received, it just echos it back, and if none is received, it prints `Nothing new`.

```
import sys
import select
timeout = 1.0
while True:
    rlist, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if len(rlist):
        print(sys.stdin.readline())
    else:
        print('Nothing new')
```

You could adapt this to wait for both user input and for a new message that you want to print to the user's console.

Comment: This works fine on Linux, but on Windows file objects are not allowed for select. Throws error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK): Socket operation on nonsocket. An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.